# Spring boot + keycloak application not working when deployed to tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I've integrated keycloak with my spring boot application. It's working when I run it using spring boot run. But when I create a war and deploy to tomcat, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
```

Is there anything I need to do to deploy this to tomcat?

Here is my `application.properties` file:

```
# keycloak configuration
keycloak.realm=salary-plus
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=salary-plus-api
keycloak.credentials.secret=8dd03031-60ac-4ef5-9ae5-19a2e3460da2
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
```

And here is my spring security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/disbursement/**").hasAnyRole(
                        "disbursement_maker", "disbursement_checker")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/disbursement/request").hasRole("disbursement_maker")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/disbursement/item/*").hasRole("disbursement_maker")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/api/disbursement/request/update/*").hasRole("disbursement_maker")
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .denyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For deploying as a WAR file you need to use the Keycloak Spring Security adapter or the Tomcat adapter, instead of the Spring Boot adapter. From the [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter):

> If you plan to deploy your Spring Application as a WAR then you should
>   not use the Spring Boot Adapter and use the dedicated adapter for the
>   application server or servlet container you are using. Your Spring
>   Boot should also contain a web.xml file.